# Image in grid is not showing up in magento 1.9.3.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am trying to add Image column in the existing module. but images are not showing up. here is the screenshot. [image: Here is the screenshot. .]

8 and 9 are having the image because I added it in MySQL.

here is my code.
Grid.php

```
   $this->addColumn('file', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('tv_faq')->__('Image'),
    'align'     =>'left',
    'index'     => 'file',
    'renderer' => 'tv_faq/adminhtml_renderer_image',
    'width'     => '150px'
    ));
```

form.php

```
    $fieldset->addField('file', 'image', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('tv_faq')->__('Image'),
        'class'     => '',
        'required'  => false,
        'name'      => 'file',
        ));
```

TV/Faq/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/Image.php

```
    public function render(Varien_Object $row){
    if($row->getFile()!=''){
        $image = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$row->getFile();
        return sprintf('<img src="%s" width="150px" alt="%s"/>',$image, $this->escapeHtml($row->getTitle()));
    }
}
```

FaqController.php

```
    public function saveAction()
{
    // check if data sent
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        // init model and set data
        $model = Mage::getModel('tv_faq/faq')
        ->setCreationTime(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate())
        ->setImage($data['file'])
        ->setData($data)
        ->save();


        // try to save it
        try {
            // save the data
            $model->save();

            // display success message
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(
                    Mage::helper('cms')->__('FAQ Item was successfully saved')
            );
            // clear previously saved data from session
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
            // check if 'Save and Continue'
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array (
                        'faq_id' => $model->getId() ));
                return;
            }
            // go to grid
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;

        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // display error message
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            // save data in session
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            // redirect to edit form
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array (
                    'faq_id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('faq_id') ));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

src of image 
[image]

Comment: What is the src for your image currently showing?

Comment: @SukumarGorai  <td class="a-left ">
                        &nbsp;                    </td>

Comment: can you check image src code  get or not?

Comment: @sania image src of 8th question is <img src="http://127.0.0.1/mag/media/blog_1.jpg" width="150px" alt="">

Comment: @sania I added this image blog_1.jpg using MySQL. how can I add the image in Magento backend?

Comment: you can check free module in banner extension code  there is backend side image display on grid so u have better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, I think you might help this.

Grid.php

```
public function callback_image($value)
{
    return "<img src='".$value."' width='150' height='100'/>";
}
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn("customsliderreport_id", array(
        "header" => Mage::helper("customsliderreport")->__("ID"),
        "align" =>"right",
        "width" => "50px",
        "type" => "number",
        "index" => "customsliderreport_id",
    ));
    $this->addColumn("image", array(
        "header" => Mage::helper("customsliderreport")->__("Image"),
        "index" => "image",
        'filter' => false,
        'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_image')
    ));
....
}
```

Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField("image", "text", array(
    "label" => Mage::helper("customsliderreport")->__("Image"),
    "name" => "image",
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in TV/Faq/Block/Adminhtml/Renderer/Image.php

```
<?php
class TV_Faq_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row){

            $html='<img ';
            $html.= 'id="'.$this->getColumn()->getId().'"';
            $html.= 'src="'.Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . DS.$row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()).'"';
            $html.= 'width="100" height="100"';
            $html.= 'class="grid-image '.$this->getColumn()->getInlineCss(). '"/>';
            return $html;
    }
}
?>
```